# was trying to run an algorithm, error obtained while loading the dataset can this be resolved? how can it be resolved in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was trying to run an algorithm. An error occurred while loading the dataset, can this be resolved? How can it be resolved in python?
The code to load the dataset is:

```
region = "testingX"
filename = region + ".csv"

x = np.array(pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], header=None))
y = np.array(pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[10], header=None))
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Maximum Open Credit'`

Comment: try like `np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';', usecols=range(10), header=None)`

Comment: Tried it getting an error :TypeError: loadtxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

Comment: Can you link your data somewhere?

Comment: @pygo Current Loan Amount,Credit Score,Annual Income,Monthly Debt,Years of Credit History,Months since last delinquent,Number of Open Accounts,Number of Credit Problems,Current Credit Balance,Maximum Open Credit,Bankruptcies
611314,747,2074116,42000.83,21.8,0,9,0,621908,1058970,0
266662,734,1919190,36624.4,19.4,0,11,0,679573,904442,0
153494,709,871112,8391.73,12.5,10,10,0,38532,388036,0
176242,727,780083,16771.87,16.5,27,16,1,156940,531322,1

Comment: Read the docs.  You have a header line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a header, which you must indicate in `read_csv` with `header=0` like:

```
pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@kull1n

Comment: Welcome! Accept the answer if it solved your question.